# How to import database table as custom post type and custom fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, mysql

I have a sql table that contains vehicle information. When I import the database table to my WordPress website, I need the information to be imported as custom fields for a custom post type. For example, I created the vehicle custom post type and the custom fields:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'vehicle',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Vehicles' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Vehicle' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            )
        ); 
}

add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init() {
    add_meta_box("vehicle_info-meta", "vehicle Information", "vehicle_info", "vehicle", "normal", "low");
}

function vehicle_info() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $stockNumber = $custom["stockNumber"][0];
    $vin = $custom["vin"][0];
    $make = $custom["make"][0];
    ?>
    <p><label>Stock Number:</label>
    <input name="stockNumber" value="<?php echo $stockNumber; ?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Vin Number:</label>
    <input name="vin" value="<?php echo $vin; ?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Make</label>
    <input name="make" value="<?php echo $make; ?>" /></p>
    <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details() {
    global $post;

    update_post_meta($post->ID, "stockNumber", $_POST["stockNumber"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "vin", $_POST["vin"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "make", $_POST["make"]);
}
```

Now that the custom post type is created, when I import my database table, I need a new vehicle post to be created for each vehicle in the database table. I also need the custom fields for each vehicle to be populated.

Answer (score 1):

// There's a confusion in which method you are importing your external table into WordPress. If someway you have parsed you external table data into a PHP variable ex: $data, then it would be simple to import.

```
foreach( $data as $_dt )
{
    $new_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_type' => 'vehicle',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title' => $_dt['vehicle_name']
    ));
    if( !is_wp_error($new_id) )
    {
        update_post_meta($new_id, "stockNumber", $_dt["stockNumber"]);
        update_post_meta($new_id, "vin", $_dt["vin"]);
        update_post_meta($new_id, "make", $_dt["make"]);
    }
}
```

// Now regarding the data source, if you have already imported your custom table into your WordPress Database, use this simple code to grab the data from it -

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $your_table_name");
```